# checking if USB is available and checking for mp3 and mp4 files with python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm making a script that checks is there is an USB drive inserted/available.
If there is a USB drive available it checks if there are .mp3 and .mp4 files on that drive and places the path to these files in a list.

Now I got the part where it can check the if there are any files but it doesn't check if there is a usb or anything available.

This script has to be running in the background and execute the searching for files part when there is an USB available.

This is my code so far:

```
import fnmatch
import os
from logging import root
import pyudev
import threading



mp3files = []
mp4files = []


# to find mp3 files in the usb given the pattern ".mp3" and the path to usb
def findmp3(pattern, path):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for file in files:
            if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, pattern):
                mp3files.append(os.path.join(file))
    return mp3files


# to find mp4 files in the usb given the pattern ".mp4" and the path to usb
def findmp4(pattern, path):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for file in files:
            if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, pattern):
                mp4files.append(os.path.join(file))
    return mp4files

# this was to test if the searching part works
# findmp3('*.mp3', '/media/pi/')
# findmp4('*.mp4', '/media/pi/')
# print(mp3files, mp4files)

class USBDetector():
    ''' Monitor udev for detection of usb '''

    def __init__(self):
        ''' Initiate the object '''
        thread = threading.Thread(target=self._work)
        thread.daemon = True
        thread.start()

    def _work(self):
        ''' Runs the actual loop to detect the events '''
        self.context = pyudev.Context()
        self.monitor = pyudev.Monitor.from_netlink(self.context)
        self.monitor.filter_by(subsystem='usb')
        # this is module level logger, can be ignored
        LOGGER.info("Starting to monitor for usb")
        self.monitor.start()
        for device in iter(self.monitor.poll, None):
            LOGGER.info("Got USB event: %s", device.action)
            if device.action == 'add':
                self.findmp3('*.mp3', '/media/pi/')
                self.findmp4('*.mp4', '/media/pi/')

            else:
                # some function to run on removal of usb
                self.on_deleted()

    print(mp3files, mp4files)
```

I'm running this script on a raspberryPi, the raspberry sets the USB drive under '/media/pi/'.
If there is no USB inserted there won't be any mp3 or mp4 files in that directory. If there is it searches through all folders and sub folders after 'media/pi/'

When I run this script it gives back an empty list, but when I run it without the USBdetector class it does give back the right files.

Is there a way to accomplish this? so that when there is an USB available it searches for those files and puts them in the list.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `self.findmp3()`: why is it `self` (function is in the global scope)? What is expected to happen afterwards? The `print(mp3files, mp4files)` is presumably gone by the time the thread does something.

Comment: You have to differentiate several things here: USB available ≠ USB device attached ≠ USB drive attached ≠ a partition on the drive ≠ the partition is mounted ≠ the data in the mounted partition is accessible to the current user. Which case do you want to check for?